# where the error happend i cant find it..new in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Installed ***android-studio-ide-191.5791312-windows.exe***.

When I started a empty activity there have some error in ***activity_main.xml*** and I could't see the preview. where is the error?

**My coding**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >
```

Comment: what are the error?? and is that your full Xml file?

Comment: yeah it is the full XML file and the error is "preview is going on loading".

Comment: after the installation i started a blank activity project and then this is happend in layout